# Composable DML error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following composable dml and I cant seem to set it working. Could someone help me point out where I've gone wrong?

```
INSERT INTO order_kit (kit_no, order_id) 
SELECT 
    X.kit_no, 10089 
FROM 
    (
    MERGE INTO kit AS tgt 
    USING
        (SELECT TOP 2 kit_no 
         FROM kit rk, batch rb 
         WHERE rk.study_id = 35 AND 
         rk.batch_id = rb.batch_id AND 
         rb.depot_id = 16 AND 
         rk.treatment = 1 AND 
         rk.status = 1 AND 
         rb.status = 1 AND 
         rb.expiry > CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() AS float)) AS datetime)
         ) AS src ON tgt.kit_no = src.kit_no 
         WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET status = 6 OUTPUT $action as action, kit_no) AS X
```

Invalid column name 'kit_no'. (*on the last line)

The target table 'order_kit' of the INSERT statement cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship when the FROM clause contains a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. Found reference constraint 'FK_order_kit_order'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to resolved this by using

```
INSERT INTO order_kit (kit_no, order_id) 
SELECT 
    X.kit_no, 10089 
FROM 
    (
    MERGE INTO kit AS tgt 
    USING
        (SELECT TOP 2 kit_no 
         FROM kit rk, batch rb 
         WHERE rk.study_id = 35 AND 
         rk.batch_id = rb.batch_id AND 
         rb.depot_id = 16 AND 
         rk.treatment = 1 AND 
         rk.status = 1 AND 
         rb.status = 1 AND 
         rb.expiry > CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() AS float)) AS datetime)
         ) AS src ON tgt.kit_no = src.kit_no 
         WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET status = 6 OUTPUT $action as action, **tgt.kit_no**) AS X
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess when you haven't supplied your table definitions, but I would guess the first error is because you have an unqualified `kit_no`. Make it

```
SELECT TOP 2 rk.kit_no
```

and see what happens.

Also, I would think the second error would be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You have to qualify `kit_no` in the output clause.

```
OUTPUT $action as action, src.kit_no
```

I actually don't understand how you can get both errors. SQL Server usually just complains about one thing at a time with a query.

You can solve the second issue by creating a table variable the you `output into` instead and use that table variable as a source to insert rows to `order_kit`.

**Update**

You can simplify this a bit by using update instead of merge and do the output directly into `order_kit`.

```
update top (2) rk
set [status] = 6
output inserted.kit_no, 10089 into order_kit(kit_no, order_id)
from kit as rk
  inner join batch as rb
    on rk.batch_id = rb.batch_id 
where
  ...
```